# Compiling a specific boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I only require a single .lib and .dll but I don't want to go through compiling process of all using `bjam.exe` How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool to create just the subset of Boost that you need.

Answer (score 13):

to compile specific library you just need to specify it with `--with-library` option, e.g. `--with-date_time`, [more info here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#invoke-bjam)